# Короткое имя пользователя учетной записи Microsoft

Tags: windows, windows-10

**Windows 10**. По какой-то причине имя пользователя учетной записи **Microsoft** состоит лишь из **5** символов. При регистрации на сайте указывал адрес электронной почты в **13** символов, а на компьютере отображаются только первые **5**. Какие могут быть причины?

Comment: У себя данной проблемы не наблюдаю. Какая сборка винды, обновлялась ли?

Answer (score 0):

Странно, эту ошибку исправили ещё в 2016 году.

К сожалению, лучшее решение - сохранить все данные, удалить старого пользователя, завести нового локального пользователя, привязать локальный экаунт к учётной записи MS.